# How can I resolve "Property does not exist error" with shared typescript projects in vscode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

Our enterprise app uses typescript for both node and angular. We have a shared typescript project that is used by both for common classes and such. It's shared using symlinks. When I make a change in the shared project, the node project does not immediately pick up the change. I get the error "Property X does not exists on type Y". I have to pretty much restart vscode to get it to work, or I go and open the .d.ts file so vscode realizes the new method/property exists.

I think I'm missing a configuration somewhere. I feel like vscode should be able to automatically pick up changes. Why is it not?

Here are the details...

VSCode: 1.33.0
Typescrit: 3.2.4
Node: 10.15.0

Shared project's tsconfig.json...

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "test/*",
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "dist/*"
    ]
}
```

Excerpt of node project's dependencies in package.json...

```
"dependencies": {
    "shared": "file:../shared",
},
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61218 might help.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but no, that's a different issue. I've already looked through most of the issues I could find.

Comment: can you update your question with resources you have tried?